# How do I fix an if statement to expect a command?

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, goto

I have an if statment checking if variable "root" is equal to 'File" but when I do it says it doesn't expect the following command.

```
@Echo Off
setLocal
:StartUpConfiguration
Cls
Color 0A
Title ACP

:Start
Set Input=nul
Set /P Input=[%CD%]
For /F "tokens=1,2* delims=." %%a In ('Echo %Input%') do (
   Set Root = %%A
   Set Function = %%B
   Set Execute = %%C
)
If %Root%==File Goto File
If %Root%==File If %Function%==Exist Goto File.Exist
If %Root%==File If %Function%==Run Goto File.Run
Goto Start
```

When I  set input to "File", it says "Goto was unexpected at this time." and then closes. I have tried to debug the problem but I just can't figure it out. I have checked if "root"nis an enviorment variable and it isn't. Maybe it has something to do with the "setLocal"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Root = %%A
```

sets a variable `root_` to a value `_File` (with spaces; I wrote `_` to show clearly where)
You have to write

```
Set Root=%%A
```

or even better

```
Set "Root=%%A"
```

Also the `for`variable is case sensitive: `%%a` is NOT `%%A`